# How to stream data from Firebase REST API to Beckhoffs's PLC using SSE (TwinCAT3)?

Tags: rest, firebase-realtime-database, plc, twincat, st

I can normally read data from Firebase Realtime Database via `REST API` through `.GET` requests. And the same applies for writing data with `.PUT` requests. But in the [Firebase Realtime Database REST API documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database#section-streaming) it is specified that you can also set a SSE listener (EventSource / Server-Sent Events ).

Thus far I have

1. Set the `Accept` header to `"text/event-stream"` as stated in the documentation (with `FB_IotHttpHeaderFieldMap` and its method     `AddField`).
2. Set the `HTTP` security layer `SSL` (so that PLC would communicate with `REST API` through `HTTPS` as needed by the documentation).

But now I can't wrap my head around what I should do next ...

- How would you approach this problem?
- What is the next step into setting an SSE listener?
- And if there is no built-in way to do this - is it possible to code
  it by myself?

---

**Using:** TwinCAT XAE (VS 2017) on Windows 10

Comment: I see I got `-1`, could you please elaborate why so? So I can edit my question better.

Comment: I didn't down vote, but I think it is because your question is about the SSE listener. However in the title this is not mentioned. Plus point 1 seems to be your real question and has no value being in that list. Finally the bold text seems more to express your frustration, that an important part of the question ;).

Comment: Ah makes sense, I will edit the question ASAP.